# Count result of many joins in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have this query:

```
    select count(*) 
            from seller s 
            left join product pr on s.id = pr.seller_id 
            left join special_price_discount spd on pr.id = spd.product_id 
            left join product___tag pt on pr.id = pt.product_id 
            left join tag t on pt.tag_id = t.id 
            left join product___size ps on ps.product_id = pr.id
```

In db I have two products, how I get right count result, because now I get 19 instead of 2.

I tried add 'group by pr.id', but then query returns 2 results, with 'distinct' I also have 19.
Or there are too many joins and I cannot gain appropriate result?
Any ideas?

Comment: What is your target? The number of products? Or the number of products that fulfill a certain condition? Can you phrase it?

Comment: I want to get the number of products return by above query, 2 in this case.

Comment: This query may not be doing what you'd expect it to do, because of indirect cross joins or "proxy cross joins" as I like to call them. Consider [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result).

Answer (score 1):

You could do e.g. `select count(distinct product.*)`.

Or more simply, if counting the products is what you really want:

```
select count(*) from products;
```

Comment: I have to consider WHERE clause where are some conditions related with joins.